# All site interaction through a single page

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, iframe

I have an idea for a site where there would be no refreshing and all interactions take place via AJAX.
The page would load with central space, where all interaction would take place.
If a user clicked on a link, the page would request it via AJAX and replace the rectangle's content with the link content.

The idea is effectively an AJAX implemented iframe.

Are there any disadvantages with this approach?
Does anyone have any suggestions or thoughts on the idea?

Thank You for your time

Note: I am sorry if it is not clear or hard to understand, English is not my mother tongue.
If there is anything you would like made clearer, please comment and I will try my best to make it understood.

Comment: @closers: I don't know why you think this is *"Not a real question"*. OP is asking about the possible disadvantages of having a single page site where all new content is loaded via AJAX.

Comment: @Robert: What's that all about? Isn't this a place to ask questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should duplicate this functionality with non Ajax content otherwise search engines would ignore inner content which is not good for SEO
2. Think about those who don't have Ajax enabled.
3. Do it in a way like this

a href="nonajaxpage.html" onclick="Ajax-call();return false;"

In this case all search engines would follow nonajaxpage.HTML and JavaScript enabled browsers would follow ur JavaScript calls

Comment: agree. you can do this, but you have to do it both ways (in the above mentioned method) if you want to get any search engine traffic. you will also have to make sure you manually prevent things like rapidly clicking something that calls ajax, that should only ever be called once (basically disabling interface while loading ajaxed content). I have done sites like this before. you tend to wonder in some cases why you did it, considering it adds more work, and for most of the calls, does not improve performance.

Answer (score 3):

I have done this. **Do not do this**, its a bad idea unless you have a REALLY good reason.

**Do this if:**

- you cant afford real hosting and must do everything with html
- you want a "web 2.0" looking site while not being able to afford real hosting
- you want to experiment with ajax

**Dont do this if:**

- you can afford real hosting and write some dynamic pages
- you want good "seo"
- you know where to use ajax for good UX

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you want to let search engines crawl all the pages accessed using AJAX or not. If you want to use AJAX for the entire site and also want your content to be indexed by Google, check these [guidelines](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html) for making crawlable AJAX applications.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not a bad idea, and I personally developed many sites (but small ones) in this mechanism.
advantages include to have one template for all pages without any master page or ...
But you need to consider some issues:

All of your pages need to have two method for displaying the content:

1. one ajax mode
2. the other for the initial view

when the user left click on on of your links the container should be filled by the coming ajax content and if the user open the link in a new tab your content should come up using the classic mechanism.

for example you may have a link like this:

```
<a href='index.jsp?page=aboutme' onclick='loadPage("aboutme"); return false'>About me</a>
```

you have solved the problem! but still there is a problem!
emagin that the user enters the website. The URL is www.yoursite.com that is equal to www.yoursite.com/index.jsp?page=home (you may have such a piece of code that evaluate **null** page as home) if the user clicks the link he see the **about me** page but if he/she refreshes the page (F5) he will see the home page again, since the url is intact.
So I suggest you to have links like this:

```
<a href='index.jsp#aboutme' onclick='loadPage("aboutme"); return false'>About me</a>
```

And using a javascript function in the page load evaluate the page value and show the appropriate page. An exmaple of such a website developed by me is here: http://www.pgcup.com (sorry it is in Persian)

Good luck!